# How to play MP3 from Twilio's WebRTC while call in progress?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-php

I have successfully setup Twilio's JS WebRTC client and the PHP side to place calls. However, I can't seem to figure out how I can send new TwiML code once the call is in progress.

Here's what I'd like to do: once the call is going I'd like to play a pre-recorded message when I click a button in my browser. What's the best way to achieve this? I can't figure out how to send a new  after the call is already in progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To send more TwiML to a call in progress you need to use the REST API to update the call that is taking place.

To do this, you will need the Call SID. You can get this from either the parameters to the original webhook to your server when the call is answered or via the [`parameters` attribute on the `Twilio.Connection` object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection#parameters).

Once you have the Call SID, you can then update the call with new TwiML by calling the REST API, like so:

```
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "{{ account_sid }}"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$call = $client->account->calls->get("{{ call_sid }}");
$call->update(array(
    "Url" => "{{ new_url_with_twiml }}"
));
```

There's more on how to update calls in flight here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

Comment: Can you explain a bit about "new_url_with_twiml"?
Also is there a better way to do this now?

Comment: With `new_url_with_twiml` I just mean the URL in your application where the TwiML that you want to direct the call to lives. If you want to change a call mid flight, then this is the way. :)

Comment: @philnash is there any way to just send twiml to living call? To say for example 'wait a second, I am ordering your pizza'? Without changing url?

Comment: No, the only way to change what a call is doing is to redirect it, as in the example above.